# fill gaps in sequence within data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have data

```
dat <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3), week=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,3), val=c(1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10))
> dat
   id week val
1:  1    1   1
2:  1    2   2
3:  1    3   3
4:  2    1   5
5:  2    2   6
6:  2    3   7
7:  3    1   9
8:  3    3  10
```

where for `id=3`a value is missing for week 2. I want to fill these gaps with `val=0` and wonder how this can be done.

I have tried to get `weeks <- 1:3` and join this with `dat` but it did not help.

Comment: Use the function provided by @Frank in the linked post: `completeDT(dat, cols = c("id", "week"), defs = c(val = 0))`

Comment: or noting that dplyr/tidyr works on data.tables: `tidyr::complete(dat, id, week)`